# Grails - showing the right class name

Tags: grails

I have simple hierarchy:

```
class Atom {}

class Text extends Atom { String value}

class Unit { 
    List atoms
    static hasMany = [ atoms:Atom ] 
}
```

Let's say we create one Text object and one Unit object, and select Unit as a parent of Text. It works fine. When I call show method on Unit, I see that my Unit consists of one Atom. When I clicking on this atom, it redirects me to atom controller, but my atom is actually text, and I want to see Text controller. It is expected behavior, because in my show.gsp there is such code:

```
<g:each in="${unitInstance.atoms}" var="a">
    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="atoms-label">
        <g:link controller="atom" action="show" id="${a.id}">
            ${a?.encodeAsHTML()}
        </g:link>
    </span>
</g:each>
```

Okay, database stores the actual atom type in field "class", so I edited the line 3:

```
<g:link controller="${a.class}" action="show" id="${a.id}">
```

And ${a.class} always return atom.
So, my question is - how can we get actual class name?

Comment: Does {a instanceof Text ? 'Text' : 'Atom'} work when used as value for the controller attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably hitting the [GORM Gotcha](http://blog.springsource.org/2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/) about Hibernate returning proxies instead of inflated objects.

In your link you could try:

```
<g:link controller="${Atom.get(a.id).getClass()}" ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but how.about adding a method in Atom and overriding it in Text, that returns the appropriate string?